# How do I pass a script argument to a pipelined argument?

Tags: mail-command

I have the following code and I wanted the argument to `-s` to include the  first argument of my bash script. Currently it prints "$1" verbatim for subject though the message body has `$1` evaluated correctly in the `echo` statement

```
echo "Converse Log Labels $1" | mailx -a conversation_logs_"$1".tsv -s "Converse Logs Labels Data "$1"" username@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are closing your quotes just before the `$1` and then opening and closing a new set after. You could try:

```
echo "Converse Log Labels $1" | mailx -a conversation_logs_"$1".tsv -s "Converse Logs Labels Data $1" username@example.com
```

or if you want the quotes included:

```
echo "Converse Log Labels $1" | mailx -a conversation_logs_"$1".tsv -s "Converse Logs Labels Data \"$1\"" username@example.com
```